# How can I debug UITableView not displaying rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a viewcontroller

```
class PlacesVC: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMap", sender: kill)
    }
}
```

I also have the id for the cell as `Cell`

[image]

When I build and run the app, I kept getting empty table

[image]

I was hoping to get the 4 rows like this.

[image]

How would one go about debugging why my rows are not showing up?

Comment: `UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")` --> `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)`

Comment: I can see 4 for with the default UITableViewController in storyboard and the codes you shared. Can you please share more detail?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, nope, I still see empty. Also, what is wrong with the current one I got ? Is it outdated syntax ?

Comment: @EmreÖnder.  What can I provided ? I don't know how to debug this thing yet. I'm new to iOS.

Comment: implement heightForRowAt ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan : What should I set it too ?

Comment: Can you please try to add a NEW UITableViewController inside storyboard and just assign it to your class and give cell a true identifier. Let us see what happens

Comment: @Sh_Khan Add it like this : https://i.imgur.com/6LoRbwJ.png , still not seeing it.

Comment: @EmreÖnder, you give me a hint, I forgot to assign class to my tableVC. Silly me, :(

Comment: So I'm writing the answer :)

Comment: Have you set the correct class for the table view controller in your storyboard? Replace `UITableViewController` with `PlacesVC`

Comment: @AshleyMills, that was the issue, `Emre` brought that up. Noob mistake guys, so sorry !

Comment: That's a "we're all human" mistake!

Comment: check whether tableView.dataSource is nil or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your class inside Identity Inspector section of your `ViewController`  on Storyboard.

[image: Like in below picture]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure that you've set the `delegate` and `dataSource`  properties of tableView to that viewController's instance (otherwise those methods will not get called).  (You can skip this step if your ViewController is inherited from TableViewController).

The second thing, you're initiating a new instance of cell for every row instead of reusing it.
So replace this line:

```
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

with:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

The 3rd thing: make sure that you've set the right class from IB.

And the last thing:  change the style from "Custom" to "Basic" in order to have the default `textLabel`.

Comment: Actually, he doesn't need to set those properties cuz It is already a UITableViewController. Maybe the storyboard has a normal UIViewController but class is a UITableViewController?

Comment: So sorry guys, turn out that I forgot to assign a class to my tableVC. By doing this : https://i.imgur.com/ALfXsVv.png , now it works;

Comment: If you want to check to see if the delegate is hooked up add breakpoints to your existing methods, if they get hit then the delegate is set. I'll wager they don't get hit though…

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   return 60
}
```

if you want it dynamic

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: The issue was the class missing !

Comment: Without heightForRowAt function, I still see the rows. Just letting you know;

Comment: yes but it's the ones the system set to avoid collapse when it doesn't find heightForRowAt or dynamic cell constraints which met your current settings

Answer (score -1):

check you have added the tableView `delegate` and `dataSource` in your code.

Register a class (if you are using a custom class) for use in creating new table cells. In `viewDidLoad()` like: 
 

 `tableView.register({your cell class}, forCellReuseIdentifier:"identifier")`

initialize the cell object by

`tableView.dequeueReusableCell(WithIdentifier:,forIndexPath:)`

Just in case you are not using any class for your cell then you do not need to register your class.
You just simply initialize cell object by:

`tableView.dequeueReusable(CellWithIdentifier:)`

Comment: `delegate` and `dataSource` methods are already there in the code and it not required to the `delegate` & `dataSource` as `PlacesVC` derived from `UITableViewController`

Comment: Custom class not required to be registered in this case as OP has already added them in storyboard and set the cell's class type as custom class. It register's automatically by storyboard.

Comment: In the last part of the answer how `tableView.dequeueReusable(CellWithIdentifier:)` will return any cell if anyone register any cell implicitly or explicitly ?

Comment: Don't jumble `UITableViewCell` with `UICollectionViewCell`. Consider reading the appledoc for `dequeueReusableCell` for `UITableView`.

Comment: Sorry it's uitableviewcell class